# How to set object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have following type:

```
export type FormField = {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  mandatory: boolean;
  options?: FormFieldOptionsType;
  visibleIfIndIsVisible?: number;
  ind?: number;
  value?: string;
  dateCreatedAt?: string;
  selectItemOtherArbitraryValueEnable?: boolean;
  regex?: string;
  defaultFormFieldOptionId?: string;
};
```

Assign one value like this

```js
const saveFormField = (key: string, value: any) => {
    let formField: FormField = {
      name: reloadProps?.formField?.name ?? "",
      type: reloadProps?.formField?.type ?? "",
      mandatory: reloadProps?.formField?.mandatory ?? false,
      regex: reloadProps?.formField?.regex ?? "",
      selectItemOtherArbitraryValueEnable:
        reloadProps?.formField?.selectItemOtherArbitraryValueEnable,
    };
    formField[key] = value;
```

but `yarn build` raise an error, do you know why?

```
./pages/[lang]/formFieldOptions/[...eventId_formFieldId].tsx:134:5
Type error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'FormField'.

  132 |         reloadProps?.formField?.selectItemOtherArbitraryValueEnable,
  133 |     };
> 134 |     formField[key] = value;
      |     ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `saveFormField` function like this:

```
const saveFormField = (key: keyof FormField, value: any) => { }
```

Comment: it worked, what about the following? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087837/typescript-type-any-is-not-assignable-to-type-never

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
formField[key as keyof FormField]  = value;
```