# TypeScript: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have following type:

```
export type FormField = {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  mandatory: boolean;
  options?: FormFieldOptionsType;
  visibleIfIndIsVisible?: number;
  ind?: number;
  value?: string;
  dateCreatedAt?: string;
  selectItemOtherArbitraryValueEnable?: boolean;
  regex?: string;
  defaultFormFieldOptionId?: string;
};
```

Assign one value like this

```js
  const saveFormField = (key: keyof FormField, value: any) => {
    let formField: FormField = {
      name: reloadProps?.formField?.name ?? "",
      type: reloadProps?.formField?.type ?? "",
      mandatory: reloadProps?.formField?.mandatory ?? false,
      regex: reloadProps?.formField?.regex ?? "",
      selectItemOtherArbitraryValueEnable:
        reloadProps?.formField?.selectItemOtherArbitraryValueEnable,
    };
    formField[key] = value;
```

but `yarn build` raise an error, do you know why?

```
./pages/[lang]/formFieldOptions/[...eventId_formFieldId].tsx:125:55
Type error: Cannot find name 'valueof'.

  123 |   };
  124 | 
> 125 |   const saveFormField = (key: keyof FormField, value: valueof FormField) => {
      |     ^
```

---

If I use following signature:

```
  const saveFormField = (
    key: keyof FormField,
    value: FormField[keyof FormField]
  ) => {
```

error is sligthly different:

```
./pages/[lang]/formFieldOptions/[...eventId_formFieldId].tsx:137:5
Type error: Type 'string | number | boolean | FormFieldOptionsType | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  135 |         reloadProps?.formField?.selectItemOtherArbitraryValueEnable,
  136 |     };
> 137 |     formField[key] = value;
      |     ^
```

---

Strange with your latest edit I got this error. I thought `e.target.value` is string, seems not?!

```
./pages/[lang]/formFieldOptions/[...eventId_formFieldId].tsx:241:48
Type error: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & Element'.

  239 |               }}
  240 |               onBlur={(e: React.FocusEvent) =>
> 241 |                 saveFormField("name", e.target.value)
      |                                                ^
  242 |               }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you a union type containing all possible types inside FormField.

```js
export function saveFormField<T extends keyof FormField>(
    key: T,  value: FormField[T]
){
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I got an other error, modified slightly the question with the result

Comment: Strange, it does not accept `e.target.value` as parameter. Do you have maybe idea why? I edited question.

Comment: i think this error is unrelated. The property value simply is not in the type definition of EventTarget & Element